# GlassFish 4 couldn't create domain

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xsd, glassfish

Here is output from terminal:

```
$ asadmin create-domain personal-domain
Enter admin user name [Enter to accept default "admin" / no password]>admin
Enter the admin password [Enter to accept default of no password]> 
Failed to parse given stream against the schema xsd/schema/stringsubs.xsd.( com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.stringsubs.StringSubstitutionException: Failed to parse given stream against the schema xsd/schema/stringsubs.xsd. )
CLI130: Could not create domain, personal-domain
Command create-domain failed.
```

I have the same in NetBeans.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: I solved this problem. Before I asked this question I have been installed NetBeans version with Java EE. So I uninstalled Java EE support from NB and then add it manually, it helped.

Comment: please add it as an answer and mark it as correct, that is the way to properly close the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Before I asked this question I have been installed NetBeans version with Java EE. So I uninstalled Java EE support from NB and then add it manually, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too using linux.
In my case it was a matter of a character with accent in my path where glassfish was installed.
So make sure your glassfish path doesn't have accents or spaces or any other "strange" character.